# Multiple Databases with spring security

Tags: java, spring-security

I am trying to extend **spring security** to work with **multiple databases**, for the *authentication-provider* I'm using a customized Class *MyUserDetailsService* which extends *JdbcDaoImpl*. 
I created a class *RoutingDataSource* to do the routing to the appropriate database and did the necessary XML configuration, but I don't get any routing, even by debugging, the application never executes the code lines of the RoutingDataSource class.
What is wrong about this code? How can I fix it ?

```
public class RoutingDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {


    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        String lookUpTenantDataSource = (String) ThreadLocalContextUtil.getTenantId();
        return lookUpTenantDataSource;
    }

    @Override
    public Logger getParentLogger() throws SQLFeatureNotSupportedException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
}
```

the XML configuration:

```
<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="com.mycompany.bean.RoutingDataSource">
        <beans:property name="targetDataSources">
            <beans:map>
                <beans:entry key="tenant1" value-ref="tenant1DataSource"/>
                <beans:entry key="tenant2" value-ref="tenant2DataSource"/>
            </beans:map>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
     <beans:bean id="tenant1DataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />        
        <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tenant1_si" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="xxxx" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="xxxx" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="tenant2DataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />        
        <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tenant2" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="xxxx" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="xxxx" />
    </beans:bean>

<beans:bean id = "myUserDetailsService" class = "com.mycompany.bean.MyUserDetailsService">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </beans:bean>

   <sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <sec:authentication-provider user-service-ref="myUserDetailsService">
            <sec:password-encoder hash="md5"/>
        </sec:authentication-provider>
    </sec:authentication-manager>
```

MyUserDetailsService class :

```
public class MyUserDetailsService extends JdbcDaoImpl {


    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyUserDetailsService.class);

    private static final String COMPTE_EJB_LOOKUP_PATH = "java:comp/env/compteFacadeLocal";

    @EJB(name = "compteFacadeLocal", beanInterface = CompteFacadeLocal.class)
    private CompteFacadeLocal compteFacade;

    private SystemFacadeLocal systemFacade;



    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) {

        User user;
        Compte compte = getUser(userName);
        if (compte != null) {
            user = new User(compte);
            if (user.isEnabled()) {
                if (!user.isAccountNonExpired()) {
                    throw new AccountExpiredException("Ce compte a expiré");
                }
            } else {
                throw new DisabledException("Le compte de '" + userName + "' est désactivé !");
            }
        } else {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(userName + " not found");
        }
        return user;
    }

    private Compte getUser(String userName) {
        try {
            InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext();
            initialContext.lookup(COMPTE_EJB_LOOKUP_PATH);

            compteFacade = (CompteFacadeLocal) initialContext.lookup(COMPTE_EJB_LOOKUP_PATH);

            return compteFacade.findCompteByLogin(userName);


        } catch (Exception ex) {

            logger.error("Could not lookup for EJB UtilisateurFacadeLocal with lookup path " + COMPTE_EJB_LOOKUP_PATH);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Could you post your custom user details service ?

Comment: I've added it right now